# In FTP Outbound gateway, how do I get the original file name in an "mv" command?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

First, I'm listing out the files in a directory which works fine. After listing, I want to move the files to a different directory which also works. However, what doesn't work is to retain the original file name.  Here is my code;

```
@Bean(value = "moveFile")
public IntegrationFlow moveFile() {
    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .fromSupplier(() -> "/", e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
            .handle(Ftp.outboundGateway(sf(), AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.LS, null)
                    .regexFileNameFilter("(dir1|dir2|.*[0-9]|.*.txt)")
                    .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY,
                            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE))
            .split()
            .handle(Ftp.outboundGateway(sf(), AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MV, null)
                    .renameExpression("'/newdirectory/' + #remoteFileName"))
            .channel("nullChannel")
            .get();
    return flow;
}
```

#remoteFileName doesn't work here but works when I use it in an mget command, and also without going through another outbound. headers['file_relativePath'] and headers['file_remoteFile'] does not work either, which are some of the results I searched up.

Another bonus question if you don't mind, (dir1|dir2|.*[0-9]|.*.txt) regex works for me, but that is because .*[0-9] works for all my folder in that directory based on how it named. What I actually want is expression for any folder there.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

I manage to solve it. The SpEL variable was 'payload' which is the string of original file directory and file name.

```
IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .fromSupplier(() -> "/", e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
            
            .handle(Ftp.outboundGateway(sf(), AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.LS, null)
                    .regexFileNameFilter("(dir1|dir2|.*[0-9]|.*.txt)")
                    .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE,AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY))
            .split()
            .handle(Ftp.outboundGateway(sf(), AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MV, null)
                    .renameExpression("'/newdirectory/' + payload"))
            .channel("nullChannel")
            .get();
    return flow;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#remoteFileName` is a SpEL variable for the remote file in the context of the local file generation with MGET command.

The `MV` command does not have a context of remote file. It works only with one remote file. You can provide all the necessary info in the request message: payload and its headers. Then you can use their `payload` and `headers` properties in that `renameExpression`.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#using-the-mv-command